# Loop Count: Forever checkbox is checking automatically by clicking any icon like save, lcar, run or any other icon in the interface

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Loop Count: Forever checkbox is checking automatically by clicking any icon like save, clear, run, or any other icon in the interface.

please help me with it.

Comment: You must provide some value to loop, else keeping it blank will default set to Forever.

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox

> **Loop Count: [_] Infinite**

checking automatically only if you try to save empty value.

Just set Loop Count==1

[image]